# Differential of composition as a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb{K}$, $E$ some Banach space, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 2$, and  $$\mathcal{BC}^n(X,E):=\left(\left\{f\in\mathcal{C}^n(X,E)\colon f^{(j)}\in\mathcal{B}(X,E),\,0\leq j\leq n\right\},\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{BC}^n}\right),$$
where  $\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal{BC}^n}=\max_{0\leq j\leq n}\Vert f^{(j)}\Vert_\infty$.

I want to study the differentiability of the map $$\circ\;\colon \mathcal{BC}^n(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{BC}^n(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{BC}^n(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) ,\quad (g,f)\mapsto g\circ f.$$

As $\mathcal{BC}^n(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space this should make sense. I reckon you'd need to study the functions $F=\circ(\,\cdot\,, f)\colon g\mapsto (g\circ f)$ and $G=\circ(g,\,\cdot\,)\colon f\mapsto g\circ f$ to show continuous differentiability of the partial differentials of $\circ$. I understand $F$ is linear, so the only thing missing is its continuity. What about $G$?

Thanks a lot in advance.